# Argument * can only be used in COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, count, average, bq

My table looks like this:

```
examID action   timeSinceStart
a     write     300
a     answer   2535
b     answer   3834
a     answer   2900
c     write     774
d     edit     3674
c     answer   3489
a     edit     3983
c     answer    300
```

I seek the following output:

```
examID averageTime
a      2717.5
b      3834
c      1894.5
```

That is, I only look at the `actions` that are `answer`, I only write the `examID` once and another column with the `average time since start at the point of answering`.

**Is it possible to do this directly without creating a column for the sum and a column for the count, and then writing the average formula?**

My "complicated" approach doesn't work:

```
%%bigquery df_average_times
SELECT countTimes.examID, sumTimes.answerSum, countTimes.answerCount, (sumTimes/countTimes) as averageTime
FROM
 ( SELECT examID, timeSinceStart, action, SUM(*) as answerSum
 FROM `some-database.bq.results` 
 GROUP BY examID, timeSinceStart, action
 HAVING action='answer'
 ORDER BY examID) as sumTimes
 INNER JOIN
 ( SELECT examID, timeSinceStart, action, COUNT(*) as answerCount
 FROM `some-database.bq.results` 
 GROUP BY examID, timeSinceStart, action
 HAVING event='answer'
 ORDER BY examID) as countTimes
 ON falseAnswers.questionId = trueAnswers.questionId
```

The error states:

```
ERROR:
 400 Argument * can only be used in COUNT(*) at [3:58]
```

Comment: SQL has not know which column values to SUM, that why you need to specify a column name, and asterixis are hard to count......

Comment: Most SQL dialects support `AVG` directly, including, as far as I could find, BigQuery, so there's no need for subqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need below query -

```
SELECT examID, AVG(timeSinceStart)
  FROM (SELECT examID, timeSinceStart
          FROM `some-database.bq.results`
         WHERE action='answer') X
 GROUP BY examID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average time for an answer, you can use:

```
SELECT examID, AVG(timeSinceStart)
FROM `some-database.bq.results`
WHERE action = 'answer' 
GROUP BY examID;
```

If you wanted to make this conditional -- say to get averages for different actions in the same query -- you would use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT examID,
       AVG(CASE WHEN action = 'answer' THEN timeSinceStart END) avg_answer,
       AVG(CASE WHEN action = 'write' THEN timeSinceStart END) as avg_write
FROM `some-database.bq.results`
WHERE action = 'answer' 
GROUP BY examID;
```